# How does nestjs pubsub.publish serializes the object?

Tags: mongodb, redis, graphql, nestjs, subscription

I'm using:nestjs, graphql(with subscription), mongodb,typegoose.
When I try to use a scalable graphql subscription, I chose to use the lib **graphql-redis-subscription**. The problem is here:

#### When I use built-in pubsub

built-in

```
pubsub.publish('name':{name: mongodbObject})
```

This mongodbObject returned will automatically add an `id` field (string for _id) whenever I need it. I guess this has something to do with pubsub serializer or my app serializer pipe.

redisPubSub

```
redisPubSub.publish('name':{name: mongodbObject})
```

This mongodbObject will not return `id`, which makes my front end throw errors. But it does provide a serializer option to change the way it works.

#### How to get the serializer of nestjs-graphql-subscription?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to not be related to the `graphql-redis-subscriptions`. As you can see in this [PubSub loc](https://github.com/davidyaha/graphql-redis-subscriptions/blob/master/src/redis-pubsub.ts#L82), it's just doing a `JSON.stringify` if you not pass a custom serializer in options.

I found some related github issues ([here](https://github.com/nestjs/graphql/issues/1117) and [here](https://github.com/davidyaha/graphql-redis-subscriptions/issues/307)), but no solutions.

Waiting for a proper solution, I'm transforming myself the objects:

```
  @Subscription(() => [ProfileAnswer], {
    resolve: ({ profileAnswers }: Record<string, any>) =>
      profileAnswers.map(({ _id, occuredAt, ...item }) => ({
        id: _id,
        occuredAt: new Date(occuredAt),
        ...item,
      })),
  })
  @UseGuards(AccountAuthGuard)
  @UseGuards(GqlAuthGuard)
  profileAnswers(@Args('uuid') uuid: string): AsyncIterator<ProfileAnswer[]> {
    // Subscribe only to own answers
    return this.pubSub.asyncIterator<ProfileAnswer[]>(`${uuid}.answers`);
  }
```